# matlab error using CAT, Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I am trying to compute the PURE BLUE COLOR from an image and compare it to the original blue channel. Then I have to explain the advantages of using pure  colors instead of RGB channels.

This Is my code:

```
>> RGB = double( imread('players.jpeg'))/255;
>> imagesc(RGB);
```

[image]

```
>> red = RGB( :,:,1);
>> green = RGB( :,:,2);
>> blue = RGB( :,:,3);
>> pure_BLUE = blue ./ (red+green+blue);
>> imagesc(pure_BLUE);
```

[image]

however when I use this:

```
>> imagesc(cat(3,pure_BLUE,zeros(240,320),zeros(240,320)));
```

I get the following error:

> Error using cat 
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
>   consistent.

Not quite sure what goes wrong here and How I can fix this!!!!

Comment: It is because, even if you are extracting a 2D matrix from a 3D matrix, MATLAB still sees the matrices red, greend and blue it as  Hight x Width x 1 matrices. Try initializing your matrices first as 2D matrices before your extraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the two arrays you're trying to concatenate are the wrong size compared to the image. The image appears to be 176x241 so you should try:

```
imagesc(cat(3,pure_BLUE,zeros(176,241),zeros(176,241)));
```

or a more general way is to use the size of the array itself:

```
imagesc(cat(3,pure_BLUE,zeros([size(pure_BLUE) 2])));
```

Comment: tahnk u, it worked fine now, the problem was instead of using zeros(240,320), I should use zeros(176,241), then it works fine thanks.